# Requests Multipart POST with list of files and an object

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

I would like to make a post request with a list of files as well as an json object. I have a working solution for 1 file + an object, however, I'm struggling to send multiple files with it.

Here is my working solution for 1 file:

```
data={
    'ticket': (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),
    'files': ('test.png', open('C:/Users/.../test.png','rb'))
}

response = requests.post(url, files=data)
```

According to https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files I could add another 'files' entry to data. But that is not working for me.

Thanks!